# Blocky Reflections on Glass

Tags: materials, glass, reflection

I am working with a car model and getting all of the materials ready for use in my project. The side windows have a noticeable reflection issue where the reflection appears blocky. The headlight cover also has some strange artifacts. I have provided the blend file so you may be able to help me solve this issue.

Blender file download (google drive): http://bit.ly/2SFRp8n

[image: Windows show blocky reflection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your faces don't have smooth shading.
They are shaded flat, creating those ugly triangular artifacts.

Just right click you model and select smooth shading.

[image]

Comment: I had done this before, but apparently doing it again fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: Also there are two triangles (6 edges) marked as "Sharp" so even set all to Smooth they stay sharp in render. Press W > Clear Sharp (or disable "Auto Smooth" option under Data Properties > Normals, but since your car is one object I dont think you want this :)